# HMA not available : Loading DOS Low

Tags: batch-file, dos, virtual-pc

I have a problem with my virtual PC running on DOS 6.22 (I know too old), and I had to create a sort of routine to copy some files from the virtual disc to the physical one. I did this by adding a line in autoexe.bat where I call my script.

The problem is that, even if the script is working perfectly fine, i get some errors when booting the machine :

[image: HMA not available]

I tried to search about it on Google, but all I get is a freaking VPN Guru ads on every link listed. 
Has anyone encountered this problem ? And were you able to solve it ?

Thanks for your attention.

Comment: If you get the same links on every page you click on a topic, it's entirely possible that you have some kind of malware, for example a browser extension, that displays foreign ads on any page. Check your computer!

Also: Specific reason for *MS*-dos? there's the much more awesome and mostly-compliant freedos.

Comment: This isn't a programming issue; it belongs on [SuperUser](http://superuser.com/).

Comment: Also, double-check that himem.sys is actually where config.sys expects it to be - it may just be looking in the wrong location.

Answer (score 0):

That's not really an error.

[HMA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High_memory_area) being available under MSDOS just means that MSDOS can take parts of the OS from the below-640k memory range and move it just above 1M. Now, unless you have software that for any crazy 80's reason needs much memory under 640kB, you'll be fine.

Real errors are the missing files. You've somehow borked your MSDOS installation, probably by moving/deleting those files.

Comment: Thanks for replying,
I've checked all the files, they're all at the C:\DOS directory.
The thing is, when I delete the "call copylog.bat" (my script) line in autoexec.bat I don't have those errors anymore.

But I really need to execute this script.